# Angular TemplateRef variable

Tags: angular

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it.
I am using Angular 8.
In the directive time.directive.ts, I don't understand how the "this.templateRef" is initialized.
I don't see it initialized. Is it initialized in the constructor?

application.component.html:

```
            <ul *appTimes="5">
              <li>Hi there!</li>
            </ul>
```

time.directive.ts:

```
            import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

            @Directive({
              selector: '[appTimes]'
            })
            export class TimesDirective {

              constructor(
                private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
                private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>
              ) { }

              @Input('appTimes') set render(times: number) {
                this.viewContainer.clear();
                for(let i=0; i < times; i++) {
                  this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, {});
                }
              }
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's initialized in the constructor, thanks to [the dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)